# Translation for "adventure"

Tags: english-to-latin-translation, vocabulary

One of the meanings of the word *adventure* is "exciting or remarkable experience", e.g.

> - *Alice's **Adventures** in Wonderland*
> - They were looking for **adventure**.
> - Working with children can be a fascinating **adventure**.

Smith & Hall's gives **facinus**, but it means just "a deed", which is far from "an adventure". Are there any better ways to express?

Comment: For Alice's Adventures in Wonderland translation into Latin the title set was "Alicia in Terra Mirabili" without a literal translation of the word adventure.  Translations of titles have many different reasons for taking their final form in another language, though might adventure be best expressed and the words of the title read better in Latin, by having the word adventure made implicit with the story taking place in a wonderland?

Comment: @Kotoba Trily Ngian: You might need to define the nature of the "adventure". The "Alice-in-Wonderland" thing is a fantasy (Latin, "phantasia"); "looking for adventure" could mean anything: a war, a Virgin-Atlantic flight into space, a walk through the Amazon jungle ("iter" = "journey", might be a good one); "working with children" is hard work which can be rewarding ("praemium").

Comment: I doubt whether the various senses of English *adventure* could be captured in a single Latin word. What comes to mind: *acta, iter, Odyssia, excursio*.

Answer (score -1):

The English word “journey” is pretty close in meaning to the word “adventure”. Journey in Latin is “iter”. That’s the closest Latin word I can think of for adventure.

Comment: Can you add to your answer a discussion on how well this works for the three examples in the question?